# Change a branch name in a Git repo

Tags: git, git-branch

How do I rename an existing branch in a Git repo?

I want the current branch to have a new name.

Comment: accept an answer @Alex or say why you don't want to accept it.

Comment: @CharlieParker It probably has something to do with the fact that this was Alex's only question, and he probably hasn't logged in since: "Last seen Feb 3 '11 at 21:29"

Comment: @J.B. OMG are you saying something may have happened to him???!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Could the highly voted answer to this be accepted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I rename a local Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591213/how-do-i-rename-a-local-git-branch)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I rename both a Git local and remote branch name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590083/how-do-i-rename-both-a-git-local-and-remote-branch-name)

Answer (score 507):

Assuming you're currently on the branch you want to rename:

```
git branch -m newname
```

This is documented in the manual for `git-branch`, which you can view using

```
man git-branch
```

or

```
git help branch
```

Specifically, the command is

```
git branch (-m | -M) [<oldbranch>] <newbranch>
```

where the parameters are:

```
   <oldbranch>
       The name of an existing branch to rename.

   <newbranch>
       The new name for an existing branch. The same restrictions as for <branchname> apply.
```

`<oldbranch>` is optional, if you want to rename the current branch.

Comment: Or `git branch -m other-branch renamed-other-branch` if you're not.

Comment: Also, if you've pushed the old branch to a remote, you can delete it with `git push origin :branchname`. That would allow you to push the new one and delete the old one, essentially renaming it on the remote.

Comment: @mipadi, it creates the new branch and don't delete the previous one.

Comment: git branch (-m | -M) [<oldbranch>] <newbranch>

Didn't work for me, giving the syntax error.

Comment: @MohammedArif With `-m`, it *renames* the old branch, so it *does* delete the previous one.

Comment: @MohammedArif Perhaps you could ask a new question if the command doesn't work for you? With or without the `-m`/`-M` options, it *should* work :)

Comment: @RichardFearn, I was mentioning mipadi, not to you actually :)

Comment: @MohammedArif: With the `-m` flag, it will rename `other-branch` to `renamed-other-branch`. The `other-branch` name will no longer exist.

Comment: It does @mipadi, that's where written down the comment, I had to remove it using 'git push origin :branchname'

Comment: @MohammedArif: When you rename it, it won't be removed from any remotes, just your local repo.

Answer (score 222):

If you're currently on the branch you want to rename:

```
git branch -m new_name
```

Or else:

```
git branch -m old_name new_name
```

You can check with:

```
git branch -a
```

As you can see, only the local name changed 
Now, to change the name also in the remote you must do:

```
git push origin :old_name
```

This removes the branch, then upload it with the new name:

```
git push origin new_name
```

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20150929104013/http://blog.changecong.com:80/2012/10/rename-a-remote-branch-on-github

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, the highly voted answer by Richard Feam only covers local repo, this one covers remote.

Comment: Agreed with the comment above, this answer was more complete in my case. Also, when I pushed additional commits to the remote branch after doing all the steps mentioned in this answer, git tried to push to the `old_name` branch again. Fortunately, git also supplied a fix in the command line: `git-branch --unset-upstream`. After this, all pushed commits went to the `new_name` remote branch.

Comment: beware that this way you lost the faculty to push with `git push` because you gent a warning whi says `Your branch is based on 'old_name, but the upstream is gone.` A `git push -u origin new_name` solve it.

Comment: This is the perfect answer which handles both remote and local branch renaming, thanks a lot.