# How can I rename a local Git branch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch

How can I rename a local branch which has not yet been pushed to a remote repository?

Related:

- [Rename master branch for both local and remote Git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/rename-master-branch-for-both-local-and-remote-git-repositories?answertab=votes#tab-top)
- [How do I rename both a Git local and remote branch name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30590083/how-to-rename-a-remote-git-branch-name/30590238#30590238)

Answer (score 18910, accepted):

To rename the current branch:

```
git branch -m <newname>
```

To rename a branch while pointed to any branch:

```
git branch -m <oldname> <newname>
```

`-m` is short for `--move`.

---

To push the  local branch and reset the upstream branch:

```
git push origin -u <newname>
```

To delete the  remote branch:

```
git push origin --delete <oldname>
```

---

To create a `git rename` alias:

```
git config --global alias.rename 'branch -m'
```

---

On Windows or another case-insensitive filesystem, use `-M` if there are only capitalization changes in the name. Otherwise, Git will throw a *"branch already exists"* error.

```
git branch -M <newname>
```

Comment: @PandaWood: it will add the new branch when you push, but won't delete the old branch. If you use `git push -f --mirror`, then it will rename the branch on the remote, but you should only use this method if the remote is simply to be a copy of your current repository. See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1526794/git-rename-remote-branch

Comment: @PandaWood, it depends on how `push.default` is configured. By default (`matching`) it will push to a remote whose name matches. You would have to do `git push origin <newname>:<oldname>` or you will create a new remote branch. However, if `push.default` is set to `upstream`, then you can `push origin head` and things will go to  the oldname on the remote.

Comment: The long name of the `-m` option is `--move`, e.g., `git branch --move master` renames the current branch to be called "master".

Comment: interesting, it seems that the rename is temporarily case insensitive, even on OSX.  Starting from **FB12.show_hide_cols**, **-m fb12.show_hide_cols** got me an existing branch error.  But **-m fb12.show_hide_col**, then **-m fb12.show_hide_cols** got me where I wanted.  afterwards, **git branch** only shows the one renamed branch, just like I wanted.

Comment: After doing this, you should also run `git push origin :<old_name> <new_name>` to update your remote branch names.

Comment: Nitpicking: Windows' file system ([NTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS)) is in fact case-sensitive. It is provisioned for systems that choose to expose the file system in a case-insensitive fashion. Windows does that.

Comment: is it possible that the old branch is not deleted in windows if i use -m, and same branch having two names and if i commit in new branch it goes ahead from older one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61367248/git-some-how-a-single-branch-having-two-names-created-how-do-i-make-it-single/61369981#61369981

Comment: You will not lose changes (unstaged/modified files) when doing this locally. Say for example you are working on a new branch... then before you commit your changes, you realize what you actually did doesn't match the name of the branch. You can safely rename it before committing the changes. This way when it's merged, the names make sense later on. -- Just wanted to add that since it wasn't mentioned in case anyone else wonders what will happen :)

Comment: I ran 
`git branch -m <newname>` followed by 
`git push origin -u <newname>` followed by 
`git push origin --delete <oldname>`. Now, the new branch has all the contents of the old branch, but the new branch is still in remote. How can this be deleted? The message showed after last command `- [deleted] <oldname>`.

Comment: @schnedan You can delete remote branches if they have been merged, which is probably the primary use case for deleting remote branches (in my experience, when not already handled by GitHub or GitLab automatically). The history is preserved in the main branch due to the merge. There's no need to keep the branch around as it is merely a label and ephemeral, from git's perspective.

Comment: @schnedan You may also want to delete if the branch is a dead-end. There's no point in keeping it around, increasingly out of date with master/main.

Comment: @schnedan Finally, a VCS is about preserving *useful* history. It is not an archaeological project. That's why we allow rebasing, amending and squashing.

Comment: `git branch -m <oldname> <newname>` worked for me after running `git push origin HEAD` afterwards.

Comment: Be VERY careful with `git push -f --mirror`! ONLY do this if the remote is a copy of your current repository. If it is a shared team repository... our team just learned that all (several hundred) open PRs were closed by this script, and then all (several hundred) open branches were deleted!

Comment: Your branch needs at least one commit, before you can rename it. Otherwise you get an error like this:

error: refname refs/heads/master not found
fatal: Branch rename failed

Answer (score 629):

You can rename a local Git branch using the following command:

```bash
git branch -m old_branch_name new_branch_name
```

Keep in mind that when you rename a branch, it still maintains its association with the old upstream branch if there was one.

To push changes to the `master` branch after renaming your local branch to `new_branch_name`, use the following command:

```bash
git push origin new_branch_name:master
```

With this command, your changes will be pushed to the `master` branch on the remote repository. However, your local branch will still be named `new_branch_name`.

---

For more details, see: [How to rename your local branch name in Git](http://madhan-tech-updates.blogspot.in/2013/01/how-to-rename-your-local-branch-name-in.html).

Answer (score 465):

To rename your current branch:

```
git branch -m <newname>
```

Comment: You will need to use -M to rename if you are only changing capitalization, as git will tell you that branch already exists.

Comment: and afterwards `git push origin HEAD:<oldname>`

Answer (score 400):

Here are the steps to rename the branch:

1. Switch to the branch which needs to be renamed
2. `git branch -m <new_name>`
3. `git push origin :<old_name>`
4. `git push origin <new_name>:refs/heads/<new_name>`

**EDIT (12/01/2017):** Make sure you run command `git status` and check that the newly created branch is pointing to its own ref and not the older one. If you find the reference to the older branch, you need to unset the upstream using:

```
git branch --unset-upstream
```

Comment: To explain the steps: 1 = switch to branch *locally*, 2 = 'move' i.e. 'rename' branch locally (`-m`), 3 = push 'nothing' to the old branch destination on the remote (i.e. delete the reference to the branch on the remote) - left side of a colon is 'source', right side is 'destination', 4 = push a reference (pointer) to the new branch, to the remote

Comment: @Milind Anantwar, what does it mean to "check that the new branch is pointing to it's own ref"? And could you please explain how `git branch --unset-upstream` resolves the unsynchronised condition(s) to which you're referring?

Answer (score 303):

Rename the branch will be useful once your branch is finished. Then new stuff is coming, and you want to develop in the same branch instead of deleting it and create the new one.

From my experience, to rename a local and remote branch in Git you should do the following steps.

> Quoting from [Multiple States - Rename a local and remote branch in
>   git](https://multiplestates.wordpress.com/2015/02/05/rename-a-local-and-remote-branch-in-git/)

#### 1. Rename your local branch

If you are on the branch you want to rename:

```
git branch -m new-name
```

If you are on a different branch:

```
git branch -m old-name new-name
```

#### 2. Delete the old-name remote branch and push the new-name local branch

```
git push origin :old-name new-name
```

#### 3. Reset the upstream branch for the new-name local branch

```
git push origin -u new-name
```

Comment: [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29650705/1030960) worked better for me.  Here the 2 steps gave me the following errors: `error: dst ref refs/heads/<old-name> receives from more than one src.; error: failed to push some refs to 'git@uri:foo/bar.git'`

Comment: You got the problem when running the command `git push origin :old-name new-name` right?

Answer (score 141):

The answers so far have been correct, but here is some additional information:

One can safely rename a branch with '-m' (move), but one has to be careful with '-M', because it forces the rename, even if there is an existing branch with the same name already. Here is the excerpt from the 'git-branch' man page:

> With a -m or -M option, `<oldbranch>` will be renamed to `<newbranch>`. If `<oldbranch>` had a corresponding reflog, it is renamed to match `<newbranch>`, and a reflog entry is created to remember the branch renaming. If `<newbranch>` exists, -M must be used to force the rename to happen.

Comment: It is overwritten by the new name/branch. For example if you have the following branches in git:
master
b1 <-- current branch
b2
after you do 'git branch -M b2' you will only have:
master
b2 <-- current branch

b1 will be gone and if you wish to recover it you should check it out by its hash. You can see it by typing 'git reflog'. Cheers.

Comment: The `-M` flag is also useful to force a rename if you are just correcting the case of the branch name, e.g. changing `myBranch` to `MyBranch`. (With `-m`, git returns `fatal: A branch named 'MyBranch' already exists.`)

Answer (score 118):

#### 1. Rename

**If it is your current branch, just do**

```
git branch -m new_name
```

**If it is another branch you want to rename**

```
git branch -m old_name new_name
```

---

#### 2. Track a new remote branch

**- If your branch was pushed, then after renaming you need to delete it from the remote Git repository and ask your new local to track a new remote branch:**

```
git push origin :old_name
git push --set-upstream origin new_name
```

Comment: If the `old_name`  branch is the default branch, you may get an error message like "The default branch of a project cannot be deleted".  In that case, you need to `git push`  the `new_name`  branch creation first, change the default branch to it, and then `git push` the `old_name`  branch removal.

Answer (score 103):

#### To rename your current  branch to a new branch name:

```
git branch -m <new_name>
```

This will set the new name for the current branch you are working with.

#### To rename another branch:

```
git branch -m <old_name> <new_name>
```

Here you have to provide the old branch name and the new branch name.

Answer (score 91):

I foolishly named a branch starting with a hyphen, and then checked out master.  I didn't want to **delete** my branch, I had work in it.

Neither of these worked:

`git checkout -dumb-name`

`git checkout -- -dumb-name`

`"`s, `'`s and `\`s didn't help either.  `git branch -m` doesn't work.

Here's how I finally fixed it. Go into your working copy's .git/refs/heads, find the filename "-dumb-name", get the hash of the branch.  Then this will check it out, make a new branch with a sane name, and delete the old one.

```
git checkout {hash}
git checkout -b brilliant-name
git branch -d -- -dumb-name
```

Comment: Ditto.  If you have to dig into the directory structure to do this magic, go all the way and do a 'mv -- -dumb-name brilliant-name'  Do a 'git branch -av' and you'll see an directory structure of .git/refs.  Or maybe 'grep -R ^ .git/refs' to see the hashes directly.

Comment: Honestly, if that's the route you wanted to take, I'd avoid the (IMO confusing and potentially dangerous if you don't know what you're doing) jaunt through .git directory in the first place, and just do it with some normal commands with some "git log" parsing (using appropriate flags to show branches, and to figure out which shasum you want to checkout a new branch from), and then do it.  Then, remove the wonky-named branch.  I _despise_ that git insists that you need to understand all of its inner workings to do some things, but greatly appreciate that you _can_ do those things.

Comment: It's harder to create a branch with a bad name in 2.10.1+.  If you do somehow do it, you can use git branch -v to get the short hash version of your branches(add -r for remote).  You can then use git rev-parse <shorthash> to get the full hash if you need it.

Comment: You can also use git show-ref this will give you the long hash of everything in your local repo.  and I mean everything...branches/stashes/tags...etc

Comment: I would consider it to be a bug in git when you cannot `checkout` that name, but can delete it.

Answer (score 88):

Just three steps to replicate change in name on `remote` as well as on GitHub:

Step 1 `git branch -m old_branchname new_branchname`

Step 2 `git push origin :old_branchname new_branchname`

Step 3 `git push --set-upstream origin new_branchname`

Comment: I had also to do one addtional thing: `git push --set-upstream origin new_branchname` which is mentioned in @Nomade answer

Comment: @Dev not in all the cases Dev, I had to update recently since using bitbucket and codecommit, step 3 is necessary

Answer (score 88):

***Update 2024***

Before we begin, make sure you’ve selected the branch you want to rename:

```
git checkout old-name
```

If you want to see all of your local branches, use the following command:

```
git branch --list
```

When you’re all clear, follow these steps:

1. Using the Git rename branch command will require you to add an **-m** option to your command:

   ```
   git branch -m new-name
   ```
2. You can also rename a local branch from another branch by using the following two commands:

   ```
   git checkout master

   git branch -m old-name new-name
   ```
3. Lastly, this command will list all — both local and remote — branches to verify that it has been renamed:

   ```
   git branch -a
   ```

Although it isn’t possible to rename a remote branch directly, the process of renaming one involves these two easy steps:

1. To start, you need to rename a local branch by following the previous steps.
   2.Then **delete** the **old** branch and **push** the **new** one. You can do this easily with the following command:

   ```
    git push origin :old-name new-name
   ```
2. Reset the upstream branch for your new local branch, and you will be all set:

   ```
   git push origin -u new-name
   ```

In the end, as **Nicolas Castro** explained in the comments, to reset the `upstream`, run two commands respectively.

```
git branch --unset-upstream

git push --set-upstream origin new-name
```

Comment: Excellent explanation. The user will probably have also to run a `git branch --unset-upstream` and later a `git push --set-upstream origin branch_name` to get everything clean.

Comment: @NicolasCastro thank-you!  Your comment was the missing piece for me and should probably be listed as part of the accepted answers

Answer (score 82):

To rename a branch locally:

```
git branch -m [old-branch] [new-branch]
```

Now you'll have to propagate these changes on your remote server as well.

To push changes of the deleted old branch:

```
git push origin :[old-branch]
```

To push changes of creation of new branch:

```
git push origin [new-branch]
```

Answer (score 71):

Trying to answer specifically the question (at least the title).

You can also rename the *local* branch, but keep tracking the old name on the remote.

```
git branch -m old_branch new_branch
git push --set-upstream origin new_branch:old_branch
```

Now, when you run `git push`, the remote `old_branch` ref is updated with your local `new_branch`.

**You have to know and remember** this configuration. But it can be useful if you don't have the choice for the remote branch name, but you don't like it (oh, I mean, you've got a *very good* reason not to like it !) and prefer a clearer name for your local branch.

Playing with the fetch configuration, you can even rename the local remote-reference. i.e, having a `refs/remote/origin/new_branch` ref pointer to the branch, that is in fact the `old_branch` on `origin`. However, I highly discourage this, for the safety of your mind.

Answer (score 50):

Rename the branch using this command:

```
git branch -m [old_branch_name] [new_branch_name]
```

`-m`: It renames/moves the branch. If there is already a branch, you will get an error.

If there is already a branch and you want to rename with that branch, use:

```
 git rename -M [old_branch_name] [new_branch_name]
```

For more information about help, use this command in the terminal:

```
git branch --help
```

or

```
man git branch
```

Answer (score 46):

Advanced Git users can rename manually using:

```
Rename the old branch under .git/refs/heads to the new name

Rename the old branch under .git/logs/refs/heads to the new name

Update the .git/HEAD to point to yout new branch name
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason to mess directly with the files instead of using the corresponding commands?

Comment: Good to know but dangerous. @U.Windl: I guess some people want to be adventurous.

Answer (score 43):

1. Rename your local branch.

If you are on the branch you want to rename:

```
git branch -m new-name
```

If you are on a different branch:

```
git branch -m old-name new-name
```

2. Delete the old-name remote branch and push the new-name local branch.

`git push origin :old-name new-name`

3. Reset the upstream branch for the new-name local branch.
   Switch to the branch and then:

`git push origin -u new-name`

Or for a fast way to do that, you can use these 3 steps:

**# Rename branch locally**

```
git branch -m old_branch new_branch
```

**# Delete the old remote branch**

```
git push origin :old_branch
```

**# Push the new branch, set local branch to track the new remote**

```
git push --set-upstream origin new_branch
```

Referance: https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/git/how-to-rename-git-local-and-remote-branches.html

Answer (score 33):

Here are three steps: A command that you can call inside your terminal and change branch name.

```
git branch -m old_branch new_branch         # Rename branch locally
git push origin :old_branch                 # Delete the old branch
git push --set-upstream origin new_branch   # Push the new branch, set local branch to track the new remote
```

If you need more: step-by-step, *[How To Change Git Branch Name](http://www.w3docs.com/snippets/git/how-to-rename-git-local-and-remote-branches.html)* is a good article about that.

Comment: Probably an existing answer (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/37320788/6607497) should have been edited instead. There are many answers saying 95% the same (which can be quite confusing).

Answer (score 31):

Probably as mentioned by others, this will be a case mismatch in branch naming.

If you have such a situation, I can guess that you're on Windows which will also lead you to:

```
$ git branch -m CaseSensitive casesensitive
fatal: A branch named 'casesensitive' already exists.
```

Then you have to do an intermediate step:

```
$ git branch -m temporary
$ git branch -m casesensitive
```

Nothing more.

Comment: Note that this situation might also arise on a Mac, which is _also_ (exceptionally annoyingly) case insensitive in its file system.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `-M` instead of `-m` to do this kind of "casing fix" rename in a single step.

Answer (score 28):

Changing the branch **locally** is quite easy...

If you are on the branch you want to change the name for, simply do this:

```
git branch -m my_new_branch
```

Otherwise, if you are on `master` or **any other branch** other than the one you'd like to change the name, simply do:

```
git branch -m my_old_branch my_new_branch
```

Also, I create the image below to show this in action on a **command line**. In this case, you are on `master` branch, for example:

[image: Change branch name locally]

Answer (score 26):

To rename the current branch (except for detached HEAD state) you can also use this alias:

```
[alias]
    mvh = !sh -c 'git branch -m `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` $1'
```

Answer (score 26):

Since you do not want to push the branch to a remote server, this example will be useful:

Let's say you have an existing branch called "my-hot-feature," and you want to rename it to "feature-15."

First, you want to change your local branch. This couldn't be easier:

```
git branch -m my-hot-feature feature-15
```

For more information, you can visit *[Locally and Remotely Renaming a Branch in Git](https://web.archive.org/web/20190912231829/http://www.benjaminlhaas.com/blog/locally-and-remotely-renaming-branch-git)*.

Answer (score 23):

If you are willing to use [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) (which I strongly recommend), you can right click your branch and chose 'Rename'.

[image]

Answer (score 22):

Another option is not to use the command line at all. Git GUI clients such as [SourceTree](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) take away much of the syntactical learning curve / pain that causes questions such as this one to be amongst the most viewed on Stack Overflow.

In SourceTree, right click on any local branch in the "Branches" pane on the left and select "Rename ...".

Comment: I wouldn't call it pain. The git command is very easy to use, once you've seen this answer, you'll probably never come back again. The problem is more that, so it seems, the *documentation* of the git command-line isn't intuitive enough.

Comment: True but with SourceTree I hardly ever need to worry about checking documentation. Everything is generally intuitive - just right click and see what the options are. (BTW I'm not affiliated with them in any way - just like the tool!)

Answer (score 22):

A simple way to do it:

```
git branch -m old_branch new_branch         # Rename branch locally
git push origin :old_branch                 # Delete the old branch
git push --set-upstream origin new_branch   # Push the new branch, set local branch to track the new remote
```

For more, see [this](https://gist.github.com/lttlrck/9628955).

Answer (score 17):

**Git version 2.9.2**

If you want to change the name of the local branch you are on:

```
git branch -m new_name
```

If you want to change the name of a different branch:

```
git branch -m old_name new_name
```

If you want to change the name of a different branch to a name that already exists:

```
git branch -M old_name new_name_that_already_exists
```

**Note: The last command is destructive and will rename your branch, but you will lose the old branch with that name and those commits because branch names must be unique.**

Answer (score 15):

If you want to change the name of the current branch, run:

```
git branch -m [old_branch] [new_branch]
```

If you want to delete the old remote branch, run:

```
git push origin :[old_branch]
```

If you want to delete the old remote branch and create a new remote branch, run:

```
git push origin :old_branch new_branch
```

Answer (score 11):

Actually you have three steps because the local branch has a duplicate on the server so we have one step for local on two steps on the server:

1. **Rename local:** just use the following command to rename your current branch, even you checked it out:

   ```
   git branch -m <old-branch-name> <new-branch-name>
   ```
2. **Delete the server one:** use the following command to delete the old name branch on the server:

   ```
   git push <remote-name[origin by default]> :<old-branch-name>
   ```
3. **Push the new one:** now it's time to push the new branch named on the server:

   ```
   git push -u <new-branch-name>
   ```

Comment: in my case 3rd command is taking care to rename remote branch, without executing above 2 nd command. Is it necessary to delete before renaming remote branch?

Comment: @SP007, The 2nd command is not essential, but I'm a little worry about clarity on git server. so I don't keep useless branches.

Answer (score 9):

Git branch rename can be done by using:

1. `git branch -m oldBranch newBranch`
2. `git branch -M oldBranch ExistingBranch`

The difference between **-m** and **-M**:

**-m:** if you're trying to rename your branch with an existing branch name using **-m**.
It will raise an error saying that the branch already exists. You need to give unique name.

But,

**-M:** this will help you to force rename with a given name, even it is exists. So an existing branch will overwrite entirely with it...

Here is a **Git terminal example,**

```
mohideen@dev:~/project/myapp/sunithamakeup$ git branch
  master
  master0
  new_master
  test
* test1
mohideen@dev:~/project/myapp/sunithamakeup$ git branch -m test1 test
fatal: A branch named 'test' already exists.
mohideen@dev:~/project/myapp/sunithamakeup$ git branch -M test1 test
mohideen@dev:~/project/myapp/sunithamakeup$ git branch
  master
  master0
  new_master
* test
mohideen@dev:~/project/myapp/sunithamakeup$
```

Answer (score 8):

All of the previous answers are talking about `git branch -m`. Of course, it's easy to operate, but for me, it may be a little hard to remember another Git command. So I tried to get the work done by the command I was familiar with. Yeah, you may guessed it.

I use `git branch -b <new_branch_name>`. And if you don't want to save the old branch now you can execute `git branch -D <old_branch_name>` to remove it.

I know it may be a little tedious, but it's easier to understand and remember. I hope it‘s helpful for you.

Answer (score 7):

For Git GUI users it couldn't be much simpler.
In Git GUI, choose the branch name from the drop down list in the "Rename Branch" dialog box created from the menu item Branch:Rename, type a New Name, and click "Rename". I have highlighted where to find the drop down list.

[image: Rename a local Git branch]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to:

- Rename the Git repository, run: `git branch -m <oldname> <newname>`
- Delete the old branch by: `git push origin: old-name new-name`
- Commit it using: `git commit <newname>`

  - and then push using: `git push origin new_branch_name:master`
- If you want to check the status then use: `git status`
- If you want to check out then use: `git checkout`

Answer (score 3):

To rename a local branch on [GitHub Desktop](https://desktop.github.com/), click on the **Current Branches** tab (to the right of current repository), right click on the branch you want to rename and click on rename. You will then be prompted with a popup where you can rename.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Rename a local branch:

   `git branch -m <old_branch_name> <new_branch_name>`
2. Push the new branch:

   `git push --set-upstream origin <new_branch_name>`

Answer (score 3):

> Offical Command from Git Itself. Try this one. It works for me.

The default branch has been renamed!
{oldBranchName} is now named {NewBranchName}
If you have a local clone, you can update it by running the following commands.

```
git branch -m {oldBranchName} {NewBranchName}
git fetch origin
git branch -u origin/{NewBranchName} {NewBranchName}
git remote set-head origin -a
```

Answer (score 3):

For more details on this procedure.

#### How to rename a local branch in Git

- To rename the current branch, make sure you’ve checked out and are using the branch you want to rename.

  `git checkout oldbranch`

  And then

  `git branch -m newbranch`
- If you want to, you can rename a branch when you’re working in another branch.

  `git branch -m oldbranch newbranch`

#### How to rename a remote branch in Git

If others use this branch and commit to it, you should pull it before renaming it locally. This ensures that your local repository is updated and that changes made by other users will not be lost.

- First, we need to delete `oldbranch` from the remote repository, and push `enwbranch` to the remote.

  `git push origin --delete oldbranch`
- Now we’ll push the new one to the remote,  by using -u (set upstream) option.

  `git push origin -u newbranch`

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do are the three steps:

1. Give the old branch under `.git/refs/heads` the new name
2. Give the old branch under `.git/logs/refs/heads` the new name
3. Update the `.git/HEAD` to lead to your new branch name

Comment: Manipulating files directly in folder ".git"? It doesn't sound like a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Why does life need to be hard when it can be easy? Remembering `-m` is fine as long as you rename branches day and night. However my brain refuses to allocate space to remember that.

So I use
`git branch new_name`
`git switch new_name  # could have been git checkout -b`
`git branch -D old_name`

Answer (score 0):

In PhpStorm:

VCS → Git → Branches... → Local Branches → *_your_branch_* → Rename

Answer (score -4):

```
git branch -m [old-branch] [new-branch]
```

-m means move all from [old-branch] to [new-branch] and remember you can use -M for other file systems.

Answer (score -6):

In Visual Studio:

Git → Manage Branches → Branches → *your_repository* → *your_branch* → Rename