# Can't checkout git branch started with hyphen (-)

Tags: git

I have cloned a git repository.
This repository has a remote branch something like **`-feature-abc`**.
When I type `git checkout -feature-abc`, I get:

```
error: unknown switch `e'
```

Any idea how to checkout this branch?

Comment: Try using quotation marks (") around the name.

Comment: @PMF I tried with both single quotes and double quotes, but no luck. Same error.

Comment: @PMF Disagree: `git` executable would see same strings in `argv`.

Comment: Uh, right. Not a good idea :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I am able to get things working based on VonC's [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20375299/1202487).

**Solution 1:**

`git checkout -b feature-abc origin/-feature-abc`

**Solution 2:**

> - Go into your working copy's `.git/refs/remotes/origin`,
> - find the file named "`-feature-abc`",
> - get the hash of the branch (`cat` the file),
> - Then check it out, make a new branch with a sane name,
> - Make new branch track remote branch.

```
git checkout {hash}
git checkout -b feature-abc
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/-feature-abc feature-abc
```

[Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520650/how-do-you-make-an-existing-git-branch-track-a-remote-branch)

Comment: You didn't mention that this branch was a remote one. My solutions would have worked with `origin/-feature-abc` instead of `-feature-abc`. But +1 nonetheless.

Answer (score 14):

Try using this syntax:

```
git checkout -- -feature-abc
```

Or, since August 2019, Git 2.23 and [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309):

```
git switch -- -feature-abc
```

The double hyphen syntax should help git separate the command options from the actual branch name parameter, as I explained before in "[Deleting a badly named git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309)".

---

If that doesn't work, you can follow the recipe suggested in "[How do I rename a local Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19873535/6309)"

Go into your working copy's `.git/refs/heads`, find the filename "`-dumb-name`", get the hash of the branch. Then this will check it out, make a new branch with a sane name, and delete the old one.

- Go into your working copy's `.git/refs/heads`,
- find the file named "`-feature-abc`",
- get the hash of the branch (`cat` the file).
- Then check it out, make a new branch with a sane name, and delete the old one.

  git checkout {hash}
  git checkout -b brilliant-name

  ## or

  git switch -c brilliant-name
  git branch -d -- -dumb-name

Comment: Solution 1 using '--' in checkout is not working. It gives error "error: pathspec '-feature-tipslist' did not match any file(s) known to git."

Comment: Solution 2 will not also work. There is no file name '-feature-abc' inside '.git/refs/heads' as i have no able to checkout that branch yet.