# Does the git branch renaming affect branch hierarchy?

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I'm working on a multi-branch project managed by GIT.

Our workflow is currently this one :

```
master
 |-> v1/master
     |-> v1/dev
```

Note : Each developper make a "fork" of v1/dev to realise task. Potentially we have numbers of branch heritated from v1/dev

We need to add branch whose heritate from v1/master named v1/debug.
And the current v1/dev branch have to heritate of v1/debug.

We target this new workflow :

```
master
 |-> v1/master
     |-> v1/debug
         |-> v1/dev
```

Note : Each have to continue to make "fork" of v1/dev to realise unit task.

---

I'm looking for a solution to add the intermediate branch v1/debug.

After some research, i would use the git rename branch command ([How do I rename a local Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591213/rename-a-local-git-branch)).

Is this command preserve branch hierarchy?

Could i rename v1/dev to v1/debug and after that make the new v1/dev branch whitout to make trouble in current development branch outcome from the current v1/dev branch?

Could developers will are able to merge unit branch outcome of renamed v1/dev in v1/debug?

Comment: just a note: A branch in Git is only a label for a development string, not a directory like it was in SVN. You could also rename `v1/master` to `foo`, `v1/debug` to `bar` and `v1/dev` to `whateveryouwant` and nothing will change...

Comment: I've edited my answer below to add pictures of a workflow example allowing you to create this « intermediate branch ». :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First of all, **don't rename the branch**. You could rename your local branch, but this will only apply to you. Remember that git is a distributed system. People have the right to name their local branch using a different name than the associated remote tracking branch.

For example, `v2/debug` could be the name of a local branch tracking the remote tracking branch `origin/v1/master` (I know, this doesn't make sense, but because git is a distributed system, people can name things like they want **locally**.

**Don't rename the branch remotely either**. This would mess up everything, because it wouldn't change the local repositories of your colleagues. Their local branches will continue to point to the same remote tracking branches (same name).

You just need to create a new branch and make it start at the point `v1/master` currently is.
To create it and switch to it directly:

```
git checkout -b v1/debug v1/master
```

Or to only create it but stay on your current branch:

```
git branch v1/debug v1/master
```

The branch is created locally and still needs to be pushed for others to be able to see it.

Later, the only thing you need is to change your merge workflow. From now on, stop to merge `v1/dev` directly into `v1/master`, and only merge it into `v1/debug`.
And merge `v1/debug` into `v1/master` whenever the code base is ready.

You were talking about **branch hierarchy**. Actually, branch hierarchy is « unknown » to git. It's just the way you merge (which branch into which one) which in the end makes the hierarchy.

### Workflow example with pictures

1. Initial state (only `v1/master` and `v1/dev`). Here, it is assumed that `v1/dev` is 1 commit ahead of `v1/master`. It is also assumed that we are currently on branch `v1/master`.
   [image: Initial state]
2. Run `git branch v1/debug v1/master`. This only creates a label pointing on the same commit currently pointed by `v1/master`.
   [image: Create the new branch v1/debug starting from v1/master]
3. Once the branch `v1/dev` is ready, merge it into `v1/debug`. Run `git checkout v1/debug && git merge v1/dev`.
   [image: Merge v1/dev into v1/debug]
4. Once the branch `v1/debug` is ready, merge it into `v1/master`. Run `git checkout v1/master && git merge v1/debug`.
   From now on, what you call the « hierarchy » starts to appear clearly.
   [image: Merge v1/debug into v1/master]
5. Do some work on branch `v1/dev`. Run `git checkout v1/dev` and do several commits.
   [image: Do some work on v1/dev (commits)]
6. Merge it into `v1/debug`. Run `git checkout v1/debug && git merge v1/dev`.
   [image: Merge v1/dev into v1/debug]
7. Merge it into `v1/master`. Run `git checkout v1/master && git merge v1/debug`.
   [image: Merge v1/debug into v1/master]

Now you have 3 clear branches with the wanted workflow!

Note that the graph would only look like this if you use `git merge --no-ff`. It makes things clearer in the picture so I assumed the merges are **non fast-forward**, so that we always see what happened, even if those merge commits are actually useless.