# How can I rename my master branch (without losing untracked ignored files)?

Tags: git, git-branch

I have an installation of a website with lots of subfolders like `logs/`, `useruploads/`,... that I don't need to track with Git.

I created a git repository on the server locally with

```
git init
echo 'userupload/*'>>.gitignore
echo 'logs/*'>>.gitignore
#....
git add .gitignore
git commit -a -m "initial .gitignore"
git add *
git comit -a -m "initial rest"
```

The only branch in this repo is called `master`, but I would like to rename it to `release`.

All solutions for renaming my `master` branch to `release` suggest to:

- checkout `master`
- rename it locally
- and delete the old one

But this approach would cause me to lose all untracked files in my Git folder. Surely, there is a better approach... What should I do?

Comment: It's not clear how you would lose your untracked files in the scenario you mention, or how your solution is different in any way.

Comment: My solution is different. There I don't checkout everything, rename it and delete the old branch. It is what I searched: only one command to rename the branch while leaving every thing else

Comment: you only have 1 branch so you are by default already checked out to it.  And if you rename the branch there is nothing to delete.  Right?

Comment: Try search yourself. The suggestions are different: they suggest to check out into a new location: https://www.google.com/search?q=rename+git+branch&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:de:official

Comment: In the end I found my solution. I guess it was hard to find, because I didn't know what you have to search for ( which is easy if you know the answer)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rename local Git branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591213/rename-local-git-branch)

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
git branch -m master release
```

from the manual:

```
-m, --move  
       Move/rename a branch and the corresponding reflog.
```

see: http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=git+branch+-m+master+release

---

In my case after this, I want to commit the new branch `remote` to an existing repository, so I have to:

```
git remote add origin git@mygitserver.org:mygit.git
git push origin release
```

see https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote/