# Moving commit history from few github repos to one bitbucket repo

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

***Description***: 
My Professor gave us few tasks. So I created two public repos `Task1` and `Task2` on github and normally I have done these tasks couple of days before the deadline.

And then he told us that we should have one private repo and there store all tasks and additional gave one more task. So I created new repo `FinalVersion` on Bitbucket and I cloned all my previous repos there, additionally I have done the newest task and pushed my all previous task and the new one to the brand new repo. And then my professor told us that he will check also our commits which I lose when pushed all staff on bitbucket.

***Goal***: take all commits history from these two repos `Task1` and `Task2` and put it at the beginning of `FinalVersion`

I searched it on google but found only example: `sb clone repo 1:1 using -mirror` option. I thought that I can copy the final version somewhere and then try use `-mirror` option on `Task1` and `Task2` and then do `rebease` the `FinalVersion` and put it on the latest master node.

But I think there is some better solution. What do you think?

Comment: Tip: Talk to your professor and ask him to stop changing the requirements.

Answer (score 2):

In your local cloned repo Taks1, you can add a remote to Task2 and fethc from it

```
cd Task1
git remote add task2 /path/to/local/clone/of/task2
git fetch task2
```

Assuming you did your work in one branch (`master`) for each repo, you can import that branch from Task2 in Task1

```
git checkout -b task2_master task2/master
```

Then, with the current local repo having the full history of task1 (`master` branch) *and* taks2 (`task2_master` branch), you can push everything to a brand new bare repos on BitBucket.

```
git remote set-url origin /ur/bitbucket/repo
git push --all origin
```

Comment: The problem is that I cant create new repo, all staff must be on the same `FinalVersion` repo. So when I try to fallow your advice I got  _Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote counterpart_

Comment: Then simply rename your local branches (http://stackoverflow.com/a/6591218/6309) to names which don't yet exist on the remote repo, and push them.