# How to push local git repo to remote branch?

Tags: git, github

I have got new design project in localhost and I have gotten github account with old design. I want to upload it to new branch.

1. I create new branch with web interface on the github "new-design".
2. I create local git repo: `#git init`
3. I add the remote repo: `#git remote add github url`
4. I add files and commit it all: `#git add -A`, `#git commit`
5. Now I want to upload it to github, I run: `#git push github new-design`

> error: src refspec new-design does not match any.

What I must to do? How push it to new-design brunch on the github server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that local repo branch name matches the remote branch name. When you create a new local repo the name of the branch is called `master`, and that probably already exists in the remote you are trying to push to.

To rename your local branch see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6591218/4335488

Or you can just run this command on the local repo, then push it to the github remote.

```
git branch -m new-design
```

Comment: Thank you. I have got this problem: error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/***'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.

Comment: If I will pull it, all my changes will be gone?

Comment: @gggigi If you don't have anything on the remote branch delete the remote and push the local branch again.