# Accidentally created new branch with existing name

Tags: git, version-control, duplicates, branch

I'm just starting to use branches with git, and I created yesterday a branch `foo` and pushed it to the remote. Today I wanted to work on it from home, so after running a pull I typed without thinking `git checkout -b foo`.

I know I shouldn't have added the `-b` option, because I got a message `Switched to a new branch 'foo'` and none of the code I wrote yesterday shows up in my folders so I figure I accidentally messed up the branch names.

I tried [renaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591213/how-do-you-rename-the-local-branch) the branch using `git branch -m foo bar` hoping that it would deal with the local branch only and deduplicate the branch names, but alas `git checkout foo` issued the message `error: pathspec 'foo' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

How can I retrieve the branch I created yesterday?

Comment: I am assuming all your changes after accidentally creation of foo branch is not pushed to remote. Try to reset hard your repo to what is there on the remote

Comment: Yep I did that and it seems ok :) Is that the right way to go though, if this  happens again in the future and I have uncommitted changes on other branches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you ran into was that you created a new branch that did not track the remote branch that you wanted.

I think that the most "right" way to correct this would be to set the branch to track the intended remote branch:

```
git checkout foo
git branch -u origin/foo
```

After doing that you can move your local branch to the current commit of the remote branch

```
git reset origin/foo
```

You can then add and commit any local changes. Then pull and push as usual.

(An alternative to `reset` would be to `rebase` on `origin/foo` instead, but I would not recommend that to a beginner)

Comment: Thanks a lot Klas, and sorry for taking so long to get back to you :)