# How to rename and move branch in git (bitucket/sourcetree)

Tags: git

We have a branch called `ABC-Awsome_Branch` , that is "saved" in `feature/3.0.0`, so it looks like: `feature/3.0.0/ABC-Awsome_Branch`

But the branch was created with an incorrect name, and even not in the correct folder. So the **correct** path/name had to be like: **`feature/2.5.0/DEF-Awsome_Branch`** . Now this branch contains some commits, etc...

It's possible to "move" and rename the branch to the correct name and path?

We use Bitbucket , and sourcetree.

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591213/how-do-i-rename-a-local-git-branch

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This should do the trick:

> ```
> git branch -m old_branch new_branch         # Rename branch locally    
> git push origin :old_branch                 # Delete the old branch    
> git push --set-upstream origin new_branch   # Push the new branch, set local branch to track the new remote
> ```

[Source here](https://gist.github.com/lttlrck/9628955)

Do not forget to pull before you do this, so you won't lose anything that was not previously pulled.