# How to make branch the same as origin/master

Tags: git

suppose I branched from `origin/master` to `brancha`.

I made, committed and pushed changes to `brancha` (this includes creating, committing and pushing new files).

Now, I want to make `brancha` the exact same *content* as `origin/master` again (because, say my changes were wrong and a better solution was put on `master`).

So I want my branch to basically be a new branch off of `origin/master`, but **I want my old changes to have been recorded** so I can see it later on in the history.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: that doesn't make anysense. if you have those other commits in your history, then its not the same.

Comment: why not just create a new branch, and leave the old one alone?

Comment: @DanielA.White Sorry, I don't mean "same" as in same history as well. I mean, same code and file structure. So, `brancha` should have the same code and file structure as `origin/master`.

Comment: @jdigital the branch is called `front-end-dev`. I will still be working on front end development. That is why it would be nice to have the same name. Now that I'm thinking about it, it would also be good to create a new branch for front end development (and leave the old branch alone, since the changes no longer are needed). It's just because of the name that I wanted to keep the same branch (the reason for the branch will be the same).

Comment: see [How do I rename a local Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591213/how-do-i-rename-a-local-git-branch)

Answer (score 2):

For changes to be saved you need a pointer to its current tip – e.g. tag or another branch.

```
git tag <tag_name> brancha
```

Then reset the branch so it matches the current `origin/master`:

```
git checkout brancha
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: Is `git tag <tag_name> brancha` done when I'm in the `origin/master` branch?

Comment: @user2719875 It doesn't matter as you explicitly tell it to be created at `brancha`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new commit on top of your brancha commits (that you want to keep), reflecting origin/master, I would suggest a reset --hard then soft (as in "[Practical uses of `git reset --soft`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5203843/6309)").

```
m--m--m (origin/master)
       \
        a--a--a (brancha, HEAD)
```

First, reset the index and worktree to what you want to see: origin/master

```
git checkout brancha
git branch tmp
git reset --hard origin/master

m--m--m (origin/master, brancha, HEAD)
       \
        a--a--a (tmp)
```

Problem: `brancha` history is not longer referenced: move `brancha` HEAD back to its original position, but without changing the index and working tree (which both reflect `origin/master`)

```
git reset --soft tmp

m--m--m (origin/master)
       \
        a--a--a (tmp, brancha, HEAD)
```

Now you can add and commit: that should compute the relevant delta to set a new commit with the same content as `origin/master`.

```
git add .
git commit -m "Restore origin/master content in a new commit on brancha"

m--m--m (origin/master)
       \
        a--a--a----M (brancha, HEAD)
             (tmp)
```

`M` and origin/master commit should have the same content.

Answer (score -3):

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard && git clean -dffx
```

Comment: This does not answer the question at all.

Comment: @joanis That is a reason to downvote, not a reason to vote to delete in the review queue.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ok, noted. SE should improve the prompts in the LQA review queue, but noted nonetheless.