# Git: Is it possible to rename master?

Tags: git, gitlab

Is it possible to rename the `master` in git?
If that's not possible, is there a way to obtain a similar result? e.g. create a branch with a custom name (say *batman*), make that branch the new master and delete the old master?

To exemplify. This is what I have now:

```
user@machine gitprojectpath (master)
$
```

This is what I'd like to have

```
user@machine gitprojectpath (batman)
$
```

Comment: `master` is not special in git. The fact that it is very often used as the main branch is pure convention. Look at [How do I rename a local Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591213/how-do-i-rename-a-local-git-branch) for the renaming part.

Comment: @RomainValeri Not completely. In GitLab, the first branch (not necessarily named `master`) pushed to the repository becomes the *default branch* which has plenty of special meaning. It is the default branch checked out by clients on a clone, and it is the  default merge request target. Also, it is usually *protected*.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: Definitely you can! See @JonathonReinhart's answer. @Bernhard: (The name) `master` is nothing special from a technical point of view, it's just a git convention for the "default" branch. Same applies for `origin` as "default" remote name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

First, to clarify your question.

In GitLab, the first branch (not necessarily named `master`) pushed to the repository becomes the default branch which has special meaning. It is the *default branch* checked out by clients on a clone, and it is the default merge request target. Also, it is usually protected.

When you say "rename master", I assume you mean rename the branch, *and* change the default branch in GitLab.

First rename the branch locally.

```
git checkout master
git branch -m newname
```

Then push it to the server

```
git push -u origin newname
```

Now go to the GitLab web UI. Under Settings > Repository, change the "default branch" to `newname`.

You'll also want to make sure that `newname` is marked *protected* to prevent accidental loss by a force-push.

Then delete `master` on GitLab from the branches page.

---

With that said, *please don't do this*. `master` is an extremely well-known convention and this change will be surprising to other contributors.

Comment: _"please don't do this"_ - maybe the OP has used their master branch for releases and now wants to rename it to "release" (without branching) so that some other development branch can be used as the new master? No criticism, just an idea why one would do it... :-) does it make sense?

Comment: And here's another reason someone might want to validly rename it; https://www.zdnet.com/article/github-to-replace-master-with-alternative-term-to-avoid-slavery-references/