# Change name of a local branch with an apostraphe in its name

Tags: git

I created a local branch with an apostrophe in its name (the name is `Bug/1243-sth-sth-don't-show`).

After I switched to a different branch I haven't been able checkout the above branch as it shows that it can not find it.

I've tried to avoid that apostrophe, but it doesn't work and a Google search indicated that it may a bug in GitHub, but the issue has been closed.

I'm uncertain how to proceed, any help is appreciated.

Comment: By "comma", I believe you mean "single quote" or "apostrophe"

Comment: I suspect your problems are merely shell quoting issues.  The following works fine to create a branch with a single quote in the name, checks it out, and then creates a new branch at the same commit: `git branch "badly-named-'-branch"; git checkout "badly-named-'-branch"; git branch better-name`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the two approaches ([mine with `--`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309), and quotes), using the [git branch rename command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6591218/6309).

```
git branch -m -- "old-name-with'-quote" "new-name"
```

(note: "`'`" is not a comma but a single quote)

[Other approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19873535/6309):

```
git checkout {hash}
git checkout -b new-name
git branch -d -- "old-'-name"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/10576762) helpful as it mentions that you can do something like `git checkout -- Bug/1243-sth-sth-don't-show` since the -- will treat all following arguments literally.