# how to clone origin master as a new local branch?

Tags: git

I have a local master modified something.I want to clone origin master as a new local branch.I tried some way as below.But I found there are some different ways between master and the new branch.I don't know why this happend.And how can I clone origin master as a new local branch totally same.

1. `git fetch origin master:newMaster`
2. `git checkout -b newMaster origin:master`

Comment: How did you check for differences between master and the new branch? Are you checking `master` or `origin/master`?

Comment: just [rename](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6591218/4648586) your local master to something else then pull the `origin/master`.

Comment: I can ran the remote master successfully , but I failed to ran local branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `git fetch origin`
2. `git checkout -b newMaster origin/master`

`origin` is the name of the remote repository you clone from. `origin/master` is what is known as a "remote tracking branch". It is how your local repository tracks the `master` branch on the `origin` repository.

`git fetch origin` updates your view of the remote repository by pulling down new commits and updating your remote tracking branches (ie. `origin/master`). Then you can simply make a branch off `origin/master` like any other branch.

See [Working with Remotes in the Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) for more.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.Why can't I just run the second line

Comment: @zyMacro You could, but then your local `origin/master` might be out of date. `git fetch` is safe, it only affects remote tracking branches.

Comment: @zyMacro Your step 1 is fine. `git fetch origin master:newMaster` does what you want. It fetches `master` from `origin` and creates a new local branch called `newMaster` at `origin/master`. Done, you don't need your step 2. Your step 2, `git checkout -b newMaster origin:master`, is incorrect and should have resulted in an error like `fatal: 'origin:master' is not a commit and a branch 'newMaster' cannot be created from it`. `git checkout` takes a branch like `origin/master`. See https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec for more about refspecs.

Comment: But in first way,  i found that there some some differences between my new local branch with origin master.My local branch had some changes inherited by my old local master.

Comment: That shouldn't be. How are you checking this diff? `git diff newMaster origin/master`? Can edit your answer with the output of `git log --graph --decorate --all --oneline` showing newMaster, master, and origin/master?

Comment: In the new branch,  I find some code based on old local master uncommited.So I think the new branch is different from the origin master.

Comment: @zyMacro To help you further I would need to see the information I've requested. Please [edit it into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58600835/edit).