# Rolling back all the changes in GIT local and remote after pushing it to remote

Tags: git

I have a merge conflict in the files. So i have to remove everything which is above the master from both local and remote.Please see the image. how do I do it. I am not sure how git reset --hard will work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are **positive** that you **must** remove your changes following your `master` and `origin/master` branch, then indeed, you can use `git reset --hard`.

You can do the following:

```sh
# Go to your branch
git checkout Release_ABCDEFG_W48.new

# Reset your Release branch to the point where master is, thus DESTROYING your work
git reset --hard master
```

If you **don't** want to loose your changes, you can use the `--soft` option to `git reset`. The documentation states:

> --soft. Does not touch the index file or the working tree at all (but resets the head to , just like all modes do)

Once you are doing deleting your work, you just have to `push --force` to your remote so that it can reflect your local changes.

Sorry for stressing out so much that you would loose work by this method, but it is a real danger. Be **sure** you want to do this.

An alternative approach is to [*rename* your branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6591213/how-do-i-rename-a-local-git-branch), move it to somewhere else, or at least back-up (in worst scenario if you can't do it with git) your work, so that you don't loose. You always have the `reflog` to save you, but better not mess with that.