# Bitbucket capitalises origin GitFlow brance name

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

When pushing a new branch to Bitucket, with a `GitFlow` prefix, it is capitalized on origin.

**Any idea why and how to change that?**

Checking out a new branch locally `release/1.0` and `hotfix/1.1.1` is changed to `Release/1.0` and `HotFix/1.1.1`

macOS Catalina
SourceTree 2.1 (I’m afraid I cannot update)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The left side of each of those arrows (`* [new branch] HotFix/5.0.4 ->` for instance) is your *local* name, which is clearly capitalized. Bitbucket has no influence over how you spell your names locally.

Comment: @torek check the local name, it is lowercase. We also checked the .git folder and it is also lowercase.

Comment: @torek But maybe the *local* git-flow extension does have an influence on how those git-flow branches are created though.

Comment: @TalZion What is your OS, OS version, Git version and which git-flow extension are you using? The nvie one or the avh one?

Comment: @VonC good point: something definitely uppercased the names somewhere. It wasn't Bitbucket, but what was it?

Comment: If you run `git ls-remote origin`, what list of branches do you see ? do you see the "lowercase" version of your branch names ? the "capitalized version" ? or both ? Same question with your local branches, when you run `git branch`.

Comment: Also : what is displayed in your first screenshot ?

Comment: @TalZion I have edited my answer to suggest a course of action.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, considering the own [Atlassian blog post](https://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2012/08/01/smart-branching-with-sourcetree-and-git-flow/) illustrating SourceTree using gitflow does not show any upercase letter:

[image: https://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/files/2012/08/flow_starthotfix-300x160.jpeg]

Nor does the "[Gitflow Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow)" BitBucket tutorial.

Check if [`gitflow-avh`](https://github.com/petervanderdoes/gitflow-avh) (installed with [`brew install git-flow-avh`](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula-linux/git-flow-avh)) works better.

My recommendation: start by [renaming those local branches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6591218/6309) (check it does change the case in refs`/heads/xxx`), and see if the issue persists