# Find the branch tag for all the changes against a feature

Tags: branch, jira, feature-branch

We use JIRA in our organisation. I am unable to find the branch tag/commit-id against particular feature. Is there something I'm missing?

To understand a feature I want to understand all the changes that were made for this feature. How do I go about finding them?

Comment: Do you use Bitbucket? Are the applications (JIRA and Bitbucket) linked?

Comment: Not sure what bitbucket is! We use JIRA and GIT..If that makes sense..

Comment: Bitbucket is the Atlassian solution for something like GitHub.

Comment: Ok! So then..What I am trying to ask here is.i am unable to find branch tag/git commits ids related to JIRA! Any clue?

Comment: By "related to JIRA" you mean related to an issue, right? See my answer below.

Comment: Does any answer solve your question? If yes, please accept an answer and show others, that this issue has been solved.

Comment: Hey, I did accept the ans. Bt I am unable to accept it as I don't have the rights yet! :)

Comment: You can't upvote it, accepting is always possible (the grey hook). See this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your JIRA is connected to some kind of source code management ([Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/product) or Github). The branch / commit name must contain the JIRA issue key.

[Jira: assign an existing git branch to an issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789652/jira-assign-an-existing-git-branch-to-an-issue)

> Creating the branch though the UI is just a convenience. The important thing is that the name contains the JIRA key. If only one developer is working on the branch, it's fairly easy to just rename (delete + add) a branch with the appropriate name.

To find all branches / commits related to an issue, there's the [Development Panel](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/viewing-the-development-information-for-an-issue-777002795.html) on the sidebar right.

Answer (score 1):

The jira key in the git commit message we found needs to be in uppsercase, well case senstive depending on what you set in the integration.